# For any DFS of a directed graph, is the strongly connected component containing the vertex with the lowest post order number also contains the sink?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

I am stumped on the following question:

For any depth first search of a directed graph, is it true that the strongly connected component containing the vertex with the lowest post order number also contains a sink?

I know that the sink has the highest post-order number, so I am inclined to say False, but I do not know if that reasoning is accurate.

Comment: Why do you say **the** sink? There may be multiple sinks, or none at all...

Comment: @Steven I mean that it contains a sink. Yes, there can be multiple sinks in the entire graph, but as long as it contains the strongly connected component contains a sink, the statement holds.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider the directed graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{1,2\}$ and $E=\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$.

The graph only contains a single strongly connected component, namely $G$ itself. However no vertex in $V$ is a sink.

Comment: So they are sometimes but not always?

Comment: I meant if there is no looping edge then the vertex with lowest postorder is a sink, right?

Comment: What's a looping edge? The graph I provided is loop-free... You mean that the graph is acyclic? If so, each vertex belong strongly to its own strongly connected component.